# How can i get the coordinates after running the function FancyArrowPatch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem about getting the vertex coordinates of the polygon drawn by the function `FancyArrowPatch`.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.plot([-199, 592], [0,0], zorder=-1000, c="k",linewidth=0.5)

arrowstyle = mpatches.ArrowStyle.Simple(head_width=14,
                                                tail_width=14,
                                                head_length=8.4)

y = 0

x1=1;x2=393

patch = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch([x1, y], [x2, y],
                                         shrinkA=0.0, shrinkB=0.0,
                                         arrowstyle=arrowstyle)

ax.add_patch(patch)
```

The picture is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpfLO.png)

I try to run the function `patch.get_path_in_displaycoord()`, but this returns

```
(Path(array([[  0.        ,   7.        ],
       [192.30080795,   7.        ],
       [384.60161591,   7.        ],
       [384.60161591,   7.        ],
       [388.80080795,   3.5       ],
       [393.        ,   0.        ],
       [388.80080795,  -3.5       ],
       [384.60161591,  -7.        ],
       [384.60161591,  -7.        ],
       [192.30080795,  -7.        ],
       [  0.        ,  -7.        ],
       [  0.        ,   7.        ],
       [  0.        ,   7.        ]]), array([ 1,  3,  3,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  3,  3,  2, 79], dtype=uint8)), True).
```

Obviously, this is not the actual vertex coordinates in the drawing, so how can i get the vertex coordinates of the drawing???

Comment: If I run the code I do get the path in display coordinates correctly. Is this a [mcve]? In which environment is this being run? Versions of libraries?

Comment: Yes, i think every one running the above codes  could get the same pictures. The version of matplotlib is 3.1.0, and i run the codes in the editor window in Spyder using the Python Console 3.6.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLLNG.png) is a screenshot of what I get in spyder with matplotlib 3.1 and python 3.6; it prints the correct path. Maybe it helps you see if you did something differently.